# css Hover problem in chrome and safari

Tags: html, css, webkit

This is the site which has a problem

http://www.clubforeducation.com/

Top menu will change its color at mouse over. All browsers except chrome and Safari. Is it a Webkit bug. If that how can i solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find setting display:block on the `<a>` works. I don't recommend li:hover because it doesn't work in IE6

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a webkit hover behavior thingy.

Check this out:
[CSS Hover + Element crashing in webkit (Chrome, Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455656/css-hover-element-crashing-in-webkit-chrome-safari)

Changing/ the selector from

```
.menu_center ul li a:hover
```

to

```
.menu_center ul li:hover a
```

Or combining both:

```
.menu_center ul li a:hover,
.menu_center ul li:hover a 
{ .... }
```

works for me.

Comment: Wow weird, had the same problem and this solved it... wished every1 just used 1 browser. I hate crossbrowser checking..

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding href="#" works as a temporary fix.  Seems like this is a pretty recent development.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best fix is to add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)on the elements that have the transition in Safari. I've got the same problem and fix it [Hover bugs with :before On Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713121/hover-bugs-with-before-on-safari/39721933#39721933)