# CSS: Link hover not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I came across [this free example website design template](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bryantsmith/anoceanofsky/) which has some links across the top. On hover, the link text and their background are supposed to change colour, according to the CSS. It works in Firefox, Opera and IE but there is no change on hover in Chrome 17.0.963.79 and Safari 5.1.2, so I'm suspecting a webkit issue. But the CSS looks innocuous enough. Where's the problem here? The part of the CSS for this hover is the following:

```
.topNaviagationLink a:hover
{
text-align:center;
border-bottom:none;
color:#0C61C9;
display: block;
width:121px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
background-image:url(tab.png);    
}
```

Comment: check if the <a> has href..hover works for links oly

Comment: are you sure that the class in your html is topNaviagationLink and not topNavigationLink

Comment: Yeah, it's 'naviagation' in both the HTML and CSS. The author made a spelling error, but it's consistent, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: If you drop `display:block;` (and add this rule to `.topNaviagationLink a`) the changes by `:hover` will work (they will be misaligned). However, I have no explanation for this behavior (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845378/css-hover-problem-in-chrome-and-safari).

Comment: I found that when using Chrome's Developer Tools and viewing a web page as a device (mobile or tablet) instead of a Web Page, that the hover functionality does not render.  This might be a "Duh..." moment for most of us, but until you realize it, it might seem like the page is not rendering correctly.  When in fact, everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's interesting...

This works, would it be acceptable?

```
.topNaviagationLink:hover a
{
text-align:center;
border-bottom:none;
color:#0C61C9;
display: block;
width:121px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
background-image:url(tab.png); 
}
```

Comment: +1. Interesting. This works too, in Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox, but not in IE. I tend to think the author made this one mistake here, rather than assuming he made a lot of mistakes elsewhere.

Comment: Well... The other answers would probably get IE working as well but this entire markup can be generally improved while offering support for all browsers. The truth is the `<div>`s that the `<a>`s are wrapped in are unnecessary. Take a look at this fiddle, its cleaner, simpler and is supported by all browsers http://jsfiddle.net/kDjnd/

Comment: Turns out the other answer screws up in IE too, more than yours does. So I accepted yours.

Comment: Surprising... IE is supposed to support the *hover* pseudo class... Are you using IE5 or earlier?

Comment: @user1090389: IE6 supports `:hover` only on links: http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16

Comment: IE 9. But as pointed out by Matthew, this is probably happening as it's rendering in quirks mode because of some badly placed comments in the HTML.

Comment: @Zeta I know, I was talking about the other solutions which are using `:hover` on their links see this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691416/css-link-hover-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari/9691937#comment12316409_9691937"

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with setting display:block only on hover. Adding display:block to the anchors from the get go fixes the problem, however it does change the display a little.

```
.topNaviagationLink a {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Remove the negative margin from .topNaviagationLink. It will look a tiny bit different but it works a lot better (the hover targets are where you would expect, etc).

Comment: The document is rendering in IE Quirks mode (otherwise known as IE6 Mode) because the author added his designed by comment before the DOCTYPE line. If you fix that, it should correct some of the issues you are seeing in IE.

Comment: Right you are. Repositioning the comment took care of the errors in both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an invisible canvas covering the link, which prevented the hover animation to trigger.