# CSS Menu Hover Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue specially in Chrome. In IE it works fine. When I hover on any menu link its background becomes black that's fine after that when I hover on some other link then the previous remains black. Similarly, when I highlight some text portion on the page it remains black forever instead of normal blue color until page is reloaded.

Here is the sample image:

[image]

In this image you see I hover 'contact Us' then 'Our Gym' then 'Success Stories' and all remains with black background forever. Also there is black rectangle appears below 'Contact Us' menu.

Can any one help me regarding this?

Comment: Add your tried code in question.

Comment: Could you add a plnkr to see your code?

Comment: @A.Alger we don't need a plnkr. StackOverflow now has a [code snippet feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: or atleast give link to your test site

Answer (score 0):

without link no one can help in anyway

but from your image and your description i can say that you css code is conflicting in some manner so all i can say now is check classes properly

or otherwise provide link

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML for unclosed elements.

If you work with HTML5: http://html5.validator.nu/
HTML4: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here [StackOverflow css hover question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845378/css-hover-problem-in-chrome-and-safari)

Someone suggested setting the a links to display:block