# jQuery: unbind hover after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code. Click "See other" button in the full screen and don't move the cursor for a second and then click "show less" button and don't move the cursor. The difference is that in the first case the behavior is normal; in the second case you can see the hover state until you move the cursor.
So how to get rid of this effect and unbind hover state?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var list = $(".partners__wrap .partner");
  var numToShow = 4;
  var button = $(".partners__button__a");
  var numInList = list.length;
  var isShowing = true;

  list.hide();
  if (numInList > numToShow) {
    button.show();
  }
  list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
  button.click(function() {
    var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
    if (isShowing) {
      list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn(500);
      onFadeComplete();
    } else {
      list.slice(showing - numToShow, numInList).fadeOut(500, onFadeComplete);

    }

  });

  function onFadeComplete() {

    var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;

    if (nowShowing == numInList && isShowing) {
      isShowing = false;
      button.text("Show less");
    } else if (isShowing) {
      button.text("Show more");

    }

    if (nowShowing == numToShow) {
      button.text("See other");
      isShowing = true;
    }

  }


});
```

```css
.partners__button {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
.partners__button__a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ff4e50;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 26px 10px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #ff4e50;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.partners__button__a:hover {
  background-color: #3cb0fd;
  border-color: #3cb0fd;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="partners">

  <h2 class="partners__h2" id="find">Headline</h2>

  <div class="partners__wrap">

    <div class="partner__1 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__1__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__1__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner__wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__2 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__2__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__2__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner__wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__3 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__3__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__3__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner_wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__4 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner_wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__5 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__1__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__1__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner_wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__6 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__2__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__2__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner_wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__7 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__3__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__3__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner_wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__8 partner">
      <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
        <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
        <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="partner_wrap">
        <h4 class="partner__name">Title</h4>
        <p class="partner__description">Text. And Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="partners__button">
  <button class="partners__button__a">See other</button>
</div>
```

Comment: in which browser are u testing? because in firefox 42.0 is working for me, with a little delay (200ms) but it's working.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your issue ; everything seems correct to me on Chrome (latest version 46.0)

Comment: Hover your cursor over "Show less" and don't move it. Then click on the button without moving.

Comment: @ArtemZ But on which browser do you see it? There is well known 'bug' regarding hover state not beeing updated without any mouse interaction but in your posted sample, i'm unable to reproduce it

Comment: Latest Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Works for me on chrome 46.0 win7. Maybe OS bug relative?!

Comment: Tested on win7 and winXP

Answer (score 0):

also working in Edge...
if u change from show to hide, the button moves, so i can't figure out that the hover state doesn't change ?!

do u mean the effect, that the button stays like half a second at same place and doesn't change?

Comment: No, the effect you're talking about is caused by fadeout.

Comment: Hover your cursor over "See other" button and it will become blue. Then click on it. The button will become normal. Then click on the "Show less" button and don't move the cursor -  the button will be blue while it should be normal again (it will become normal if you move the cursor).

Comment: if i click "show less"  and don't move my cursor, the button is moving away from my cursor because of ur fade effect and it changes his state at the moment it moves away from my cursor

Comment: anyway, if there is an bug in ur view, try to give ur button a class like "active" while hover and remove the class if mouse is moving out

Comment: **DAMN** guess i got ur problem now :D ... U want to get ur Button to become "normal" - also if the cursor is on it -  after click? - if Yes, u can't work with `css hover` .... and from Usabilty View this won't make any sense to do it like that...

Comment: I've made a little animation for you. http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=20151109170rTe1miUUTXJiowKrrP4IF&file=output_KNKsQu.gif On step #4 hover state shold disappear because the cursor isn't on the button.

Comment: okay, that helped. Now in my Microsoft Edge i got same Problem...Maybe u can solve it with this:
`$(".partners__button__a").click(function() {
 $(".partners__button__a").toggleClass("hovered");
 });` and in `css` --> `.hoverd{/*ur hover style*/}`. I can't see why it is bugging at that point, but maybe u can fix it with that little script

Comment: okay, it won't help for ur problem maybe if u Changing/ the selector from `.partners__button__a:hover ` **to** `.partners__button button.partners__button__a:hover ` like here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845378/css-hover-problem-in-chrome-and-safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845378/css-hover-problem-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But it doesn't work for for me.